# Node.js generated text boxes are filled simultaneously

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, textbox

I'm building a dynamically generated form from a database using ng-repeat in Node.js and Angular.   All of the text boxes are replicating the text entered on any one of the text boxes. So, if I type "xyz" in one text box, all of them have "xyz".  But, if I submit the results, it only updates that one form reference.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="todo-form">

<form  class="form-inline" ng-repeat="todo in todoData">
            <li>            
             <h4>Country Code: {{ todo.country_code }} <input id="{{ todo.country_code }}" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="{{ todo.country_name }}" ng-model="formData.text">
            <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="updateTodo(todo.country_code)">Update</button></h4><br>
            </li>
  </form>
  </div>
```

This is the JS it refers to:

```
    angular.module('editTodo', [])
.controller('editController', ($scope, $http) => {
  $scope.formData = {};
  $scope.todoData = {};
  // Get Org Details
  $http.get('ref_country_code_get')
   .success((data) => {
    $scope.todoData = data;
    console.log(data);
  })
  .error((error) => {
    console.log('Error: ' + error);
  });
```

Clearly, I need to disable this.  I've tried to add a name= or ID={{ todo.country_code }} into the form to make it unique, but that doesn't work.  Why are the all acting like they are the same text box?  I'm new to Node.js and very rusty with my HTML, but I can't find any reference to this phenomena. Maybe it is too basic that nobody makes this mistake?  %)

Comment: The ng-model is the same for all text boxes - try changing it to "todo.text"

Comment: Fantastic!  That worked!

Answer (score 0):

Andy F solved the issue.  Simply replace the ng-model="formdata.txt" to ng-model="todo.txt".  Now, none of the text boxes replicate what is typed in any other text box.